# Can the domain of $f(x)/g(x)$ be larger than that of $f(x)$ or $g(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following two functions:

$f(x) = \sqrt {4 - x^2};\;\{x : x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ge -2 \,\ \text{and} \ \, x \le 2\}$

$g(x) = \sqrt {1 + x};\;\{x : x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ge -1\}$

Given that:

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}} = \sqrt{\frac{4-x^2}{1+x}}$$

Is the domain of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ determined by the first step or only the last?

For instance, does the domain include $-3$?

If the domain is determined by the first step, then the answer would be NO, because both $\sqrt{4-(-3)^2}$ and $\sqrt{1+(-3)}$ are imaginary.

However, if the domain is determined by the second step, then the answer would be YES, because $\sqrt{\frac{4-(-3)^2}{1+(-3)}} = \sqrt{\frac{-5}{-2}} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is a good question: at its core, it boils down to *how you define a function*. A function is not defined by an expression, but by a *domain* and and an expression (let's say, for simplicity; that second part is not entirely accurate). But the curriculum seems to forget that last part and only define it via an expression, which is the source of quite a lot of confusion...

Comment: Might be worth noting that $\frac {\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}} \ne \sqrt{\frac {4-x^2}{1+x}}$ which makes the question moot.

Comment: @fleablood Then ask the same question with $f=g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ by $f(x)=1/x$, with the question being whether $0$ is in the domain?

Comment: Maybe, but we still have the question of pole removing, for instance $f(x)=(x-x_0)h(x)$ and $g(x)=(x-x_0)$ or even continuity extension like $\dfrac{\sin(x)}x$.

Comment: Great first question @jwool.

Answer (score 3):

This only depends on your definition of your new function (call it $h(x)$).

If $h : x \mapsto \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ then the domain of $h$ is limited to the intersection of domains of $g$ and $f$.

If you define
$h : x \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{4-x^2}{1+x}}$ then the domain of $h$ can be larger

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  As you have it set up, the answer is no.

Let $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, and assume $x$ was in the domain of $h(x)$.  Then $h(x)$ exists, which means by definition that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exist.  So $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and $g$